# In Ember, what is the difference between this and this.controller

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js, ember-data

I'm attempting to build a simple Ember application that collects information from a form.  I'm using [this tutorial](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/javascript/ember-js/components-save) as a guide.  In the tutorial it has the following code to grab information from a form:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
  actions: {
    saveRental1() {
      var params = {
        owner: this.get('owner'),
        city: this.get('city'),
        type: this.get('type'),
        image: this.get('image'),
        bedrooms: this.get('bedrooms'),
      };
      ...
      this.sendAction('saveRental2', params);
    }
  }
});
```

here is a bit of the relevant form code:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image URL</label>
        {{input value=image id="image"}}
      </div>

      <button {{action 'saveRental1'}}>Save</button>
    </form>
```

In my solution I could not get this to work. this.get('whatever') always showed up as 'undefined' in my code.  After a bit of debugging I was able to find a solution, but it meant changing my code from `this.get('city')` to `this.controller.get('city')`

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong or why?  Is it 'standard' to use this.controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template context will be the controller. Route `model` hook return data will be set in controller `model` property through `setupController` by default. You can access the controller in route thorugh `this.controller`.

If you are using `this` inside the component it will refer to component instance, in your case, if you got the `city` property in component, then you can access it using `this.get('city')` in component.

Answer (score 0):

He did not update the tutorial there. Ideally, you can access as `this.get('city')` or `this.get('owner')` only if you pass the values to the component. Something like below.

```
{{new-rental city=city owner=owner}}
```

Unless you pass the values to the component you cannot access as `this.get('city')` instead you can access as `this.controller.get('city')` which is what happening in your case. Try passing the values to the component if you would like to access them directly.